# How to get firebase data in two "places"?

Tags: swift, firebase

I got how to get data from firebase to my app in a table view. My question is, how can I get it in "two places"? Is that even possible?

For example, say you want to take the user "Email" from firebase, and put in on the profile page, and the home page.  Is this possible?

If so how?  I tried duplicating the same code, but it just deletes it from one location and adds it to the new one?

```
 import UIKit
 import FirebaseDatabase
 class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, 
 UITableViewDataSource{


@IBOutlet weak var myTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var myTableView: UITableView!

@IBOutlet weak var myTableView2: UITableView!
var myList:[String] = []

var handle:DatabaseHandle?

var ref:DatabaseReference?

@IBAction func saveBtn(_ sender: Any) {

    // Saving item to database
    if myTextField.text != ""
    {
    ref?.child("list").childByAutoId().setValue(myTextField.text)
    myTextField.text = ""
    }
}


//Setting up our table view


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return myList.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
    cell.textLabel?.text = myList [indexPath.row]
    return cell
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    ref = Database.database().reference()

    handle = ref?.child("list").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

        if let item = snapshot.value as? String
        {
            self.myList.append(item)
            self.myTableView.reloadData()
            self.myTableView2.reloadData()
        }

    })

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


 }
```

Comment: Why don't you create a different class which maintains the state? Don't always recreate it.

Comment: Do you have a viewController for your homepage and a different viewController for your profile page? If so, how do you transition from one to the other? Once we have a bit more data, we can probably help.

Answer (score 0):

Consider creating a new struct which acts as the local firebase for your project

Comment: Is this an answer? What does it mean? Can you elaborate a bit to help us understand what you are suggesting?